# php 12 hr format to 24hr format time converting

Tags: php, time

I have a string like "6:15pm". Is there any function in PHP which will convert it directly to 24 hr format. ie to "18:15"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would suggest using [`strtotime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) with [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
print date("H:i", strtotime("6:15pm"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
echo date('H:i', strtotime('6.:15pm'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Call this once before the 1st date/time operation
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Zurich');

echo date('H:i', strtotime('6:15pm'));
```